# Setting imageViewResource the second time in app widget hides my listView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-appwidget

I have a listView widget that contains a button in the right top corner, and a list view. It also contains an imageView that acts as the background.
On the change of theme, I expect it to change imageView resource. I've made it change the imageView resource like so:

```
val views = RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.widget_layout)
views.setImageViewResource(R.id.imageViewBackground, R.drawable.widget_background)
```

This works smoothly when changing the theme. But on the second time of changing theme, The imageview resource changes, but the listView is gone.

Here's the full code of the onReceive method.

```
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
    if (intent.action == "android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE_OPTIONS") {
        val views = RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.widget_layout)
        val mode = context.resources.configuration.uiMode.and(Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK)
        when (mode) {
            Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES -> {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Going into night mode", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                views.setImageViewResource(R.id.imageViewBackground, R.drawable.widget_background_night)
            }
            Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO -> {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Going into light mode", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                views.setImageViewResource(R.id.imageViewBackground, R.drawable.widget_background)
            }
            Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_UNDEFINED -> {
            }
        }
        val mManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context)
        mManager.updateAppWidget(ComponentName(context, FirstMoneyWidgetProvider::class.java), views)
    }
}
```

widget_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/widget_relativeLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewBackground"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/widget_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent" />

<ImageButton .../>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Why is the listView not appearing when changing the image view resource more than one time?

Comment: you gave match parent to width so it takes full screen and the listview drawn below the imageview thats why its not appeared in screen you should use scrollview for your root layout